# Angular output with parent and child doesn't work in a button

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm passing a button event from the child to the parent, but when I click the button, nothing happens.

This is the child code

product-item.component.html

```
 <button (click)='handleShowDetail()' class="product_buttonAdd">
```

product-item.component.ts

```
 @Input()
  productItem!: Product;
```

```
  @Output()
  showDetail: EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter()
handleShowDetail(){
    
    this.showDetail.emit(this.productItem.sku)

 }
```

This is the code where the product-item is contained

product-list.component.html

```
<div class="header__searchResultsContainer">
  <div
    class="header__searchResults"
   
  >
    <lpr-product-item
    
    (showDetail)="handleShowDetail($event)"
    ></lpr-product-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

product-list.component.ts

```
 @Output()
  showDetail: EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter()
handleShowDetail(sku: string){
    this.showDetail.emit(sku)

  }
```

This is the parent who should activate the navigate and target the product based on its sku

product-container.component.html

```
<div class="product_container">
  <div><lpr-products-list 
        (showDetail)="handleShowDetail($event)"
    
    ></lpr-products-list></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

product-container.component.ts

```
 handleShowDetail(sku: string){
    this.router.navigate([ '/product-details' ])
  }
```

When I click on the button, the user should be redirected to a product detail, but nothing happens

Comment: First off, product-item passes the SKU in the output but product-list does not use it nor send it, so the sku information is lost. Even knowing that, the router should still navigate, unless the route is unknown? Could you create a fiddle or something to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Code as posted should work, some minor issues with not passing $event upwards

Comment: make sure you declare all your components in the same module

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the data ($event) from the `product-list.component.ts` to `product-container.component.html`.

product-list.component.html

```
<div class="header__searchResultsContainer">
  <div
    class="header__searchResults"
   
  >
    <lpr-product-item
    
    (showDetail)="handleShowDetail($event)"  // <-- pass parameter
    ></lpr-product-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

product-list.component.ts

```
@Output()
  showDetail: EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter()
  handleShowDetail(sku: string){
    this.showDetail.emit(sku); // <-- pass parameter

  }
```

Suggestion:
As an alternative to passing a variable trough multiple components with event emitters you could use a service.

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: You still need to pass the parameter as a route param `this.router.navigate([ '/product-details' , sku])` and read it in the `product-details` component. At this point I can suggest to provide a sandbox project link with the case.

Answer (score 0):

I created a[`stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3jegi5) of your project with the same component structure and all being declared in `app.module.ts`

```
|--product-container
|--product-list
|--product-item
```

[image: and it looks like this]

and the project look like this.

The code works well and emitted from `product item component` upto the `product container component` even using the same variable as you do.

1. make sure to declare all the component in the same module
2. make sure you wrote the right event emitter
3. make sure to import all angular core functions

see working code here: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3jegi5)